# Is it normal for a dog to eat it's dead puppies when giving birth?

Tags: dogs, breeding, death

I was following the progress of a pregnant dog. When she gave birth the owner said two of the pups were born dead and she ate them. I'd never heard of this and a dog breeder told me this was normal. It just sounds a little horrifying.

Is it normal for a dog to eat it's dead puppies when giving birth?

Comment: i do not think this is common but many animals do eat the placenta after giving birth,is it possible the owner have this confused?

Comment: @trondhansen well that's the point of the question. I'd like to know if this is true.

Comment: sounds horrifying to me

Comment: @Sonevol yeh ikr.